# Color boxes with tcolorbox in Jupyter notebook

Tags: tcolorbox, mathjax

I can't understand how to get a formula, inside a box with a background color, into a notebook. I try it as follows and it doesn't work properly. What is my mistake?. Best regards

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\begin{equation}
\tcboxmath[colback=magenta!25!white,colframe=magenta, title=Solución]
{\sum\limits_{i=1}^k P{x_i}= 1}  
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Do you expect this to work in the notebook itself (it won't, I'm pretty sure), or in a PDF generated by `nbconvert`?

Comment: I am looking for a way to do it on notebooks

Comment: The notebook isn't rendered by LaTeX, so you can't expect arbitrary LaTeX code to work. Math in notebooks are rendered by MathJax, a JavaScript library. You're probably better off looking for some HTML/CSS solution. Anyways, I think your question is off topic here, as it doesn't really have anything to with (La)TeX, [so] would be a better place to ask.